# Is there a tool that will tell me WHY I got Permission Denied?

Tags: permissions, utilities

There are several reasons you might get a "Permission denied" error in unix. Some of them are not very obvious -- for example if a parent (or grandparent, great-grandparent, etc.) directory doesn't have the executable bit set, you can't read a file further down in that tree. Maybe you're out of space. Maybe you're not in the group. Maybe selinux or something.

Is there a program that, given a particular command I'm attempting, can check all the possibilities of why I might get permission denied and tell me?

Comment: Never heard of anything like that. I'm positive it doesn't exist. There are many more situations when e.g. there's no write permissions: a read only mount point, a read only network share, etc.

Comment: Ugh, I guess I have to write it then.

Comment: Sounds very useful. Would you mind updating the post and sharing the script/program when you've done it?

Comment: Yeah, if I get around to it I will make it fully free / open source and post the link here.